# Camera Problems

Tags: image, blackberry, camera

I have run into a few problems when trying to get the camera to work accordingly... The camera Demo Works on the 8520 device (Has a memory Card) but does not work on the 9780 device (Has No Memory Card) the error given

> ERROR Class java.lang.ArrayOutOfBoundsException :index 0>=0

My code Sample:

```java
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen{

    Player _p;
    VideoControl _videoControl;
    FileConnection fileconn;
    String PATH;
    String GetfileName;
    LabelField GetPhotofileName = new LabelField("",LabelField.FOCUSABLE){
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
            Dialog.alert("Clicked");
            return true;
        }
    };

    public static boolean SdcardAvailabulity() {
        String root = null;
        Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            root = (String) e.nextElement();
            if( root.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/") ) {
            }else if( root.equalsIgnoreCase("store/") ) {
            }
        }

        class MySDListener implements FileSystemListener {
            public void rootChanged(int state, String rootName) {
                if( state == ROOT_ADDED ) {
                    if( rootName.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/") ) {
                    }
                } else if( state == ROOT_REMOVED ) {
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected boolean invokeAction(int action){
        boolean handled = super.invokeAction(action);
        if(SdcardAvailabulity()){
            PATH = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard.photos")+"Image_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";//here "str" having the current Date and Time;
        } else {
            // PATH = System.getProperty("file:///store/home/user/pictures/")+"Image_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
            PATH = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.photos")+"Image_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
        }

        if(!handled){
            if(action == ACTION_INVOKE){
                try{
                    byte[] rawImage = _videoControl.getSnapshot(null);
                    System.out.println("----------1");
                    fileconn=(FileConnection)Connector.open(PATH);
                    System.out.println("----------2");
                    if(fileconn.exists()){
                        fileconn.delete();
                        System.out.println("----------3");
                    }
                    fileconn.create();
                    System.out.println("----------4");
                    OutputStream os=fileconn.openOutputStream();
                    System.out.println("----------5");
                    os.write(rawImage);
                    GetfileName =fileconn.getName();
                    System.out.println("----------6");
                    System.out.println("GetfileName----------"+GetfileName);
                    fileconn.close();
                    System.out.println("----------7");
                    os.close();
                    Status.show("Image is Captured",200);
                    GetPhotofileName.setText(GetfileName);
                    System.out.println("----------8");
                    if(_p!=null)
                        _p.close();
                    System.out.println("----------9");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    if(_p!=null){
                        _p.close();
                    }
                    if(fileconn!=null){
                        try{
                            fileconn.close();
                        }catch (IOException e1){
                            //if the action is other than click the trackwheel(means go to the menu options) then we do nothing;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return handled;
    }

    public MyScreen(){
        setTitle("Camera App");
        try{
            System.out.println("Debug------------10");
            _p = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?encoding=jpeg&width=1024&height=768");
            _p.realize();
            _videoControl = (VideoControl) _p.getControl("VideoControl");
            System.out.println("Debug------------11");
            if (_videoControl != null){
                Field videoField = (Field) _videoControl.initDisplayMode (VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");
                _videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
                System.out.println("Debug------------12");
                _videoControl.setVisible(true);
                _p.start();
                System.out.println("Debug------------13");
                if(videoField != null){
                    add(videoField);
                    System.out.println("Debug------------14");
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(_p!=null) {
                _p.close();
            }
            Dialog.alert(e.toString());
        }
        add(GetPhotofileName);
    }
}
```

on the 8520 (Has a Memory Card) the code works fine on the 9780 (Has no Memory Card) the the code stops at "System.out.println("debug---1")", can anyone please tell me if you can see any problem with my code???

Comment: come to THIS CHAT ROOM: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-iphone-and-java

Comment: I didn't find "debug---1" message. As well that I see your code always return true in `SdcardAvailabulity` (so SD card is always available in your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public static boolean SdcardAvailabulity() {
     String root = null;
     Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
     while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
         root = (String) e.nextElement();
         if( root.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/") ) {
             return true;
         }else if( root.equalsIgnoreCase("store/") ) {
             return false;
         }
     }
     class MySDListener implements FileSystemListener {
         public void rootChanged(int state, String rootName) {
             if( state == ROOT_ADDED ) {
                 if( rootName.equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard/") ) {
                 }
             } else if( state == ROOT_REMOVED ) {
             }
         }
     }
     return true;
}
```

This is the sollution, My "SD card availability" code only returned true which caused the picture not to save when the blackberry had no memory card inserted. @  Eugen Martynov Please read through the code and you will see it is there :)